# fetch API: Can't add Authorization on Request Header with Chrome

Tags: http, cors, fetch-api, preflight

**Chrome version**: 57.0.2987

Actually, in older Chrome version I also have this problem.
I added `Authorization` on Request Header with my access token,

```
fetch('https://example.com/endpoint', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken
  }  
})
```

I always get `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization` on **Response Header** in Chrome
Besides, My fetch is always Request Method:**OPTIONS** (not display GET), then `Status Code` is 200 OK in Chrome

But if I run the same fetch code in Firefox (ver 52.0.1 ), everything works great. I can add `Authorization` on **Request Header** correctly. It won't display `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization` on **Response Header** in Firefox. It will display `Authorization: Bearer  accesstoken` on Request header.

The server side already processed CORS for my request header..

This is a Chrome bug or my code fault? How should I do to make `Authorization` on **Request Header** correctly in Chrome?

Below image is the detail **Network** in **Chrome** dev tool:
[image: Below image is the detail Network in Chrome dev tool:]

Below image is the detail **Network** in **Firefox** dev tool:
[image]

Comment: As I told you in https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/509, you really need to share more information. This is not enough to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Anne I already post the Chrome Network detail in the question, there are Request header and Response header. I hope it can be useful. do you find any clue?

Comment: I mean, that looks fine, so it's probably something else. What does the console say? Does the `fetch()` method reject?

Comment: @Anne console didn't say anything. `fetch()` did not reject. But it can't set `Authorization` on Request Header correctly, it just stop in CORS preflight step. I also post Network in firefox. it can finish CORS preflight, then to GET  method, set `Authorization` on Request Header correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure then. You might have to file a bug against Chrome. Can you reproduce it without using localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stackdave said, browser send OPTIONS request before GET request when cross-domain ajax. Then browser will wait server response. My situation that the server didn't response, so browser just stop OPTIONS status. Server need to handle this issue, it's still CORS issue, not fetch api bug or issue.

Answer (score -1):

browser will send before a OPTIONS request, without the authorisation token, and then will send the real request

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ See http://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/ for a bit more info